# Выключение экрана WinAPI C++

Tags: c++, winapi, экран

Только учусь winAPI, весь вечер вчера пытался написать программу, которая бы выключала экран и включала при нажатие на клавишу F2, код ниже. Проблема в том, что при появлении окошка нажимаю на ОК и программа закрывается, не выполняя мою функцию NewWndProc, подскажите, что делать? Решил выключать экран в цикле, т.к без него экран загорается при передвижении мышкой или нажатии на клавиатуру.

КОД С++

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <winuser.h>

struct project1 {
    LONG pPrevProc;
}ppjct1;

LRESULT CALLBACK NewWndProc(HWND   hwnd, UINT   uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    bool key = true;
    while (key) {
        SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2);
        switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_KEYUP:
            switch (wParam) {
            case VK_F2:
                {
                key = false;
                break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return CallWindowProc(WNDPROC(ppjct1.pPrevProc), hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)L"Programm is started!", (LPCWSTR)L"Screen killer", MB_OK);
    ppjct1.pPrevProc = SetWindowLongPtr(NULL, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)NewWndProc);
    SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, -1);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызов `SetWindowLongPtr` с `NULL` в качестве первого параметра ничего не делает. Выключать монитор в цикле также бесполезно, так как он по факту будет все время включаться - выключаться. Если хотите выключать экран, то придется копать глубже и отключать его полностью.

Comment: Хорошо, а какой параметр тогда использовать для SetWindowLongPtr вместо NULL?

Comment: @Игорь Никакой, у вас нет своего окна чтоб что-то в нем изменять. Можете запустить тот же самый код в цикле, проверяя состояние клавиш с помощью `GetKeyState`.

Comment: Спасибо, а подскажите целесообразно изучать API windows, это сейчас востребовано или нет смысла ?)

Comment: @Игорь Ну как в качестве примера построения долгоживущих полнофункциональных API покопаться в них стоит. И в простых сишных API, и в COM. И посравнивать с posix и прочими аналогами.